# How to read strings off of .txt file and sort them into an ArrayList based on the number of occurrences?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap, counter

I have a program that reads a .txt file, creates a HashMap containing each unique string and its number of occurrences, and I would like to create an ArrayList that displays these unique strings in descending order in terms of their number of appearances.

Currently, my program sorts in descending order from an alphabetical standpoint (using ASCII values I assume).

How can I sort this in descending order in terms of their number of appearances?

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/ahz9187/Desktop/counter.txt"));
            while(in.hasNext()){
                String string = in.next();


             //makes sure unique strings are not repeated - adds a new unit if new, updates the count if repeated
                if(map.containsKey(string)){
                    Integer count = (Integer)map.get(string);
                    map.put(string, new Integer(count.intValue()+1));
                } else{
                    map.put(string, new Integer(1));
                }
            }
            System.out.println(map);

            //places units of map into an arrayList which is then sorted
            //Using ArrayList because length does not need to be designated - can take in the units of HashMap 'map' regardless of length

            ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList(map.keySet());
            Collections.sort(arraylist);                      //this method sorts in ascending order

            //Outputs the list in reverse alphabetical (or descending) order, case sensitive

            for(int i = arraylist.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){ 
                String key = (String)arraylist.get(i);

                Integer count = (Integer)map.get(key);
                System.out.println(key + " --> " + count);
            }
```

Comment: Use a custom `Comparator`. Get the number of occurrences from the `HashMap` and compare...

Comment: And use the entrySet() not keySet(), so you have unique string and number of occurences together.

Comment: Shove all the items from the completed HashMap into a [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) using a `Comparator` like Boris said. What you want is a max heap, so that once you've put everything into the priqueue (ordering by # of occurrences) you can just  `poll()` until you've extracted all the elements.

Comment: Side note: `Integer` supports the `+` operator: `map.put(string, map.get(string) + 1);`. @BoristheSpider Why don't you answer rather than comment?

Comment: @sp00m if you insist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown the declaration of your map, but for the purpose of this answer I'm assuming that your map is declared like this:

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

You need to use a `Comparator` in the call to sort, but it needs to compare by the count, while remembering the string. So you need to put objects in the list that have both the string and the count.
One type that provides this capability, and that is easily available from the `Map.entrySet` method, is the type `Map.Entry`.

The last part rewritten with `Map.Entry` and a `Comparator`:

```
ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> arraylist = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>(map.entrySet());
Collections.sort(arraylist, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> e1, Entry<String, Integer> e2) {
        // Compares by count in descending order
        return e2.getValue() - e1.getValue();
    }
});

// Outputs the list in reverse alphabetical (or descending) order, case sensitive

for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : arraylist) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " --> " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    final Path path = Paths.get("C:", "Users", "ahz9187", "Desktop", "counter.txt");
    try (final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
        final Map<String, Integer> count = lines.
                collect(HashMap::new, (m, v) -> m.merge(v, 1, Integer::sum), Map::putAll);
        final List<String> ordered = count.entrySet().stream().
                sorted((l, r) -> Integer.compare(l.getValue(), r.getValue())).
                map(Entry::getKey).
                collect(Collectors.toList());
        ordered.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

First read the file using the `Files.lines` method which gives your a `Stream<String>` of the lines.

Now collect the lines into a `Map<String, Integer>` using the `Map.merge` method which takes a key and a value and also a lambda that is applied to the old value and the new value if the key is already present.

You now have your counts.

Now take a `Stream` of the `entrySet` of the `Map` and sort that by the `value` of each `Entry` and then take the `key`. Collect that to a `List`. You now have a `List` of your values sorted by count.

Now simply use `forEach` to print them.

If still using Java 7 you can use the `Map` to provide the sort order:

```
final Map<String, Integer> counts = /*from somewhere*/
final List<String> sorted = new ArrayList<>(counts.keySet());
Collections.sort(sorted, new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(final String o1, final String o2) {
        return counts.get(o1).compareTo(counts.get(o2));
    }
});
```